# Why does my macOS notarization example not work?

Tags: xcode, macos, notarize

I signed and exported my test application for the macOS notarization process. I can validate the ticket by using `xcrun stapler validate`

```
$ xcrun stapler validate /Users/user/Downloads/Test.app 
Processing: /Users/user/Downloads/Test.app
The validate action worked!
```

However, opening the application still triggers a warning popup. Does anyone know why? I am using the latest macOS 10.14.4 (18E226).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is working correctly. There is no "warning dialog". What you are seeing is exactly the dialog one would expect to see as a result of notarization, as shown on this page:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_your_app_before_distribution

[image]

The dialog says that Apple has checked against malware. That is what notarization *is*.

Comment: Oh, wow! I haven't seen the fine print. I somehow assumed that a notarized app would make this dialog disappear. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: I am still a bit confusing because I get the same dialog as long as it's signed with valid certificate regardless whether it's notarized or not

Comment: @laocius As the need to notarize apps is only be enforced on macOS Catalina, you will not see any difference on Mojave, but believe me, you will see a big difference when you try to run a non notarized app on Catalina.